# Using 'onset' as a verb?

Tags: word-usage

I'm aware that '**onset**' is only listed as a noun in the classical English dictionairies OED, OALD, CALD, LALD, etc.

However, since the English language seems to be 'grammatically abused' more and more, for example using the preposition 'who' for non-human objects, would it be permissible and intelligible to use 'onset' as a verb.

Exemplary senstence:
This whole compromising condition was onset over 20 years ago.

Comment: No! Don't do it, but that's just an opinion, and questions which can only be answered by opinions are off topic.

Comment: What you call "grammatical abuse" is really just natural evolution of the English language because the grammar of a language, and especially word usage aren't fixed over a longer period of time. Dictionaries' role is primarily to record usage, and not senselessly prescribe it. If English-speaking people decide *onset* could be used as a verb, then that's gonna happen (per "What is not the practice of most, or of the best, is not part of our common language."). Right now that change doesn't seem very likely.

Comment: What's interesting is its contrast with *it was offset*. The senses here are different, but, despite that, it doesn't *sound* completely ludicrous (even though I would still never use it this way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard "onset" used the way in which you do in your example. It wouldn't make any sense. We have the verbs "to begin" or "to start" to define the *action* of something beginning. *The* onset of something is *a specific moment in time* - the very beginning of the *situation*, not the verb.

Your sentence should either read:

> This whole compromising condition **began** over 20 years ago.

or

> **The onset** of this whole compromising condition was over 20 years ago.

One reason why "onset" may be used in spoken or written English without a determiner to show it is something specific is that it can be used in terminology such as "early-onset dementia", or "young-onset arthritis". In such terminology though, "*the onset*" is still the name of a specific point in time in each individual's case.